# CSS - Div not changing background color

Tags: css

So why doesn't this `<div>` change its background color?
PS: The body background is black

```css
.dayone {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="dayone">...</div>
```

Comment: It changes in this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/fuaxfjyb/  Can we see more code?

Answer (score 0):

It is changing you can't see it because it is white i changed it to green

```css
.dayone {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="dayone">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes It does. When you turn the body to black. The code you provided has nothing on the body color. So the white is not visible.

```css
body{
    background-color:black;
}
.dayone {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="dayone">...</div>
```